# Not able to install ws module in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, windows, server

I am trying to setup ogar private server in my Windows PC, for this I need to install ws module on NodeJS. I am writing the command below in command line.

*$ npm install ws*

It gives me tje output below:

*ws@1.1.0 node_modules\ws*

Help me solving this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look inside your node_modules folder. It must have been installed

Comment: What's the question and the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to install this package with sudo command:
**$ sudo npm install --save ws**

I think it should work correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

I tired that but it giving same output like below,
ws@1.1.0 node_modules\ws

Regards

Comment: I have tried and for me it works. What I can offer is that update Node and then try to install it in another directory after **$ npm init**

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Can you give detail which you done in command line and with node.

Comment: I will write all commands in order:
1. **$ mkdir my_app**
2. **$ cd my_app**
3. **$ npm init -y**
4. **$ npm install ws --save** or try this with sudo like this: **$ sudo npm install ws --save**